# Spring security antMatchers not finding sub folders

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I have placed security on a folder which only Admin has access to. Inside this folder I have an img folder with images inside. The image is not showing.

I have tried various way of accessing the image, but am affraid I am just not getting it to show.

My Java code:

```
    private String privateResources[] = new String[]{"/admin/**"};

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(publicResources).permitAll()
                .antMatchers(privateResources).hasRole("ADMIN")
```

My html code and the various ways I tried to find the image:

```
<img class="rounded-circle" src="img/logo-blue-small.png" alt="">1
<img class="rounded-circle" src="/img/logo-blue-small.png" alt="">2
<img class="rounded-circle" src="../img/logo-blue-small.png" alt="">3
<img class="rounded-circle" src="admin/img/logo-blue-small.png" alt="">4
<img class="rounded-circle" src="/admin/img/logo-blue-small.png" alt="">5
<img class="rounded-circle" src="../admin/img/logo-blue-small.png" alt="">6
<img class="rounded-circle" src="templates/admin/img/logo-blue-small.png" alt="">7
<img class="rounded-circle" src="/templates/admin//img/logo-blue-small.png" alt="">8
<img class="rounded-circle" src="../templates/admin/img/logo-blue-small.png" alt="">9
```

The path to my image on the project is:

```
src\main\resources\templates\admin\img\logo-blue-small.png
```

After successful login as ADMIN, I can see the admin page because the 1,2,3...9 next to the images are being printed, but not one of the images on any of those paths are shwing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you declared "templates" as a public folder? By default, Spring Boot only serves static resources from the folders below.

- /META-INF/resources/
- /resources/
- /static/
- /public/

If you want to serve static resources from your own folders, you need to declare it in `applications.properties`.

```
spring.resources.static-locations: classpath:templates/
```

Answer (score 3):

Put the images in the `src\main\resources\static` folder

Comment: That's the proper way I think.